# Excel 2013 SDI closing windows in multiple monitors

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a multiple monitor setup, and I am trying to close all open windows (and associated sheets) except a specific one.

So assuming the open sheets are located in:

```
Windows("Monitors.xlsm:1")
Windows("Monitors.xlsm:2")
Windows("Monitors.xlsm:3")
```

How do I replace the “Monitors.xlsm” with the current file name?
Make Windows("CurrentfileName.xlsm:1") and associated sheet the active window & sheet, then close Windows and associated sheets :2 & :3?

Comment: Not sure if there is something special in Excel 2013, but what difference does it make which monitor the workbook is on? Can you not say `Workbook(x).Close` and have it close no matter which monitor it's on?

Comment: For information on Excel 2013's SDI vs MDI see [Programming for the Single Document Interface in Excel 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn251093.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, @Jeeped, was unaware of that. Haven't had the, uh, _pleasure_ of moving into 2013 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013's Single Document Interface has some peculiarities over what you may have been used to using in previous versions' Multiple Document Interface. I believe you are looking for the `.Caption`.

```
Dim w As Object
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Windows.Count
For Each w In ThisWorkbook.Windows
    Debug.Print w.Caption
Next w
```

More information at [Programming for the Single Document Interface in Excel 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn251093.aspx).